# Trying to authenticate a password using generate_password_hash and check_password_hash. from Werkzeug. It fails

Tags: python, password-hash

I have a simple App to authenticate a user login. I wrote a test password script to ensure the authentication is working.  However, it never succeeds even though it should for my testcase.

Here is the code:

```
# Validate Form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password_hash.data
        password_hash = generate_password_hash("password", "sha256")
        # Clear the form
        form.email.data = ''
        form.password_hash.data = ''

        # Lookup User Password by email
        pw_to_check = get_user_pwd(email)    # this gets the DB password (hashed)
        # Check Hashed Password
        passed = check_password_hash(pw_to_check, password)

    return render_template("test_pw.html", 
        email = email,
        password = password,
        pw_to_check = pw_to_check,
        password_hash =password_hash,
        passed = passed,
        form = form)


def get_user_pwd(email):        # this function gets the user password by email
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            password_hash = "NONE"
            cursor.execute("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE email=email;")
            password_hash = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            return password_hash
    


HTML

{% if email %}
    <h1>Email: {{ email }}</h1>
    <h1>Password: {{ password }}</h1>
    <br/>
    <h2>I found this info:</h2>
    <br/>
    Email: {{email}}<br/>
    PW in DB (hash): {{pw_to_check}}<br/>
    PW in form (hash): {{password_hash}}<br/>
    <br/>
    Passed: {{ passed }}


{% else %}
    <h1>What's Your Email and Password?</h1>
    <br/>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {{ form.email.label(class="form-label") }}

        {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
        <br/>

        {{ form.password_hash.label(class="form-label") }}

        {{ form.password_hash(class="form-control") }}
        <br/>

        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary") }}


    </form>
```

The results from the "passed = check_password_hash(pw_to_check, password)" statement is always false.
Is there something I am missing?  It seems very simple but I am sure I got something wrong.
ANy help will be much appreciated.  -umv@merysolsecurity.com

A few things:

1 - I made sure that the password hash stored in the DB was generated using the generate_password_hash("password", "sha256")   (password=password12345 )and

2 - The password used in the login form is exactly the same (password12345)

3 - There was a similar question posted and the problem there was that the password_hash being sent to the check_password_hash function was a tupple. SO the solution was to point ot he first element of the tupple[0]. In my case, I am using password_hash = cursor.fetchone()[0] to avoid that problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `pw_to_check` and `password` right before your `check_password_hash(...)` call.

Comment: Hi Progman.  It is working now.  It was a stupid typo on the form. Thanks for your help. - Umberto